# Another combinatorics problem involving permutations and counting methods

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> A course with 2 of 'a' subjects, 3 of 'b' subjects and 2 of 'c' subjects is to be ordered in a row. The number of arrangments with 'b' subjects together is?

Again, I'm not sure what I've left out here as shouldn't the answer just be  $^3 P_3$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If:

- $\color\red   {a}$ subjects are identical to each other
- $\color\green {b}$ subjects are identical to each other
- $\color\orange{c}$ subjects are identical to each other

Then the answer is $\frac{(\color\red2+\color\green1+\color\orange2)!}{\color\red2!\times\color\green1!\times\color\orange2!}=30$

---

If:

- $\color\red   {a}$ subjects are not identical to each other
- $\color\green {b}$ subjects are not identical to each other
- $\color\orange{c}$ subjects are not identical to each other

Then the answer is $(\color\red2+\color\green1+\color\orange2)!\times\color\green3!=720$

Answer (score 0):

No, the answer is not $^{3}P_3=\frac{3!}{0!}=6$.

You should see the group of the three 'b' subjects as one object, because they must be together.

So you want to order two 'a' subjects, a 'bbb' subject and two 'c' subjects. 
 Do you know what the answer is now?

Comment: Would that be 5 choose 5 = 5!?

Comment: Oh, and hence you mutiply that by 3!?

Comment: @mathslover If all a's, b's and c's are identical, then there are $\frac{5!}{2! \cdot2!}$ possibilities, because changing two identical a's doesn't matter (and the same for two identical c's).